# Spring Integration - Control sftp polling using a boolean flag for sftp inbound adaptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Is there a way in spring integration sftp adaptor to control the polling based on a boolean flag?
Example

- boolean flag = true, then poll the directory, and get the file.
- boolean flag = false, then do not poll the directory.

Answer (score 0):

See `AbstractPollingEndpoint`:

```
/**
 * Configure a cap for messages to poll from the source per scheduling cycle.
 * A negative number means retrieve unlimited messages until the {@code MessageSource} returns {@code null}.
 * Zero means do not poll for any records - it
 * can be considered as pausing if 'maxMessagesPerPoll' is later changed to a non-zero value.
 * The polling cycle may exit earlier if the source returns null for the current receive call.
 * @param maxMessagesPerPoll the number of message to poll per schedule.
 */
@ManagedAttribute
public void setMaxMessagesPerPoll(long maxMessagesPerPoll) {
```

It is also explained in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers

> Starting with version 5.5, a `0` value for `max-messages-per-poll` has a special meaning - skip the `MessageSource.receive()` call altogether, which may be considered as pausing for this inbound channel adapter until the `maxMessagesPerPoll` is changed to a non-zero value at a later time, e.g. via a Control Bus.

You can also do such a control via `MessageSourceMutator` advice injected into the poller configuration. That one has this method to implement:

```
/**
 * Subclasses can decide whether to proceed with this poll.
 * @param source the message source.
 * @return true to proceed (default).
 */
default boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example for @InboundChannelAdapter. I am new to this.

Comment: The `@InboundChannelAdapter` has a `poller` attribute. That one can reference to the `PollerMetadata` where you can provide an `adviceChain` with an impl for that custom `MessageSourceMutator`. With the `setMaxMessagesPerPoll()` there is nothing to do: you just set it to `0` on the injected endpoint and reset it to something else whenever you need. See Control Bus also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus